# Atmosphere - isolate multiple subscriptions on single page

Tags: websocket, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I have a single page app that may have 1..n atmosphere subscriptions to a topic (the subscription is typically tied to a component that the user adds to the screen).  An issue I'm coming across is when I call unsubscribe on a single request, it unsubscribes from ALL of the requests.  You can see an example of the front-end at http://pastebin.com/c113bCNY .  I am able to successfully establish both connections, and both receive message updates independently, but when I call $.atmosphere.unsubscribe(requestOne); The onClose event fires for both and I can confirm on the server it is also closing down both subscriptions.

On the server-side, I'm using the MeteorServlet in a Spring MVC environment. (See http://pastebin.com/2Ub83LdZ for the relevant parts)  Is there something additional I need to do to isolate the two subscriptions?

Versions:

```
jQuery.atmosphere = { version: "2.2.13-jquery"}

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
    <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$.atmosphere.unsubscribe(request) DOES cancel the entire socket connection (it ignores the request parameter).  Apparently that is by design.  To cancel a single subscription call the disconnect() method on the subscription object you get back from $.atmosphere.subscribe.